# Eclipse 4 won't close correctly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I created an application with Eclipse Oxygen and when I press the red X to close the application it won't close. 
[image]

It is closing just the workbench but the process is remaining active, and when I close it from inside the application with Quit button it closes just fine.
[image: try to close]

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're talking about, I suggest you to add images to your question, and if the application you've written plays an important role in the problem, you can also attach the code.

Comment: I added 4 pictures . I hope it is ok